# ActiveStorage Uploading to S3 with original file extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I am uploading APK files to Amazon S3 via Rails ActiveStorage.
The upload is working fine, but when I try to retrieve the files, download them, I see that file extensions and content types are changed.

The APK files are being downloaded as ZIP files.

I know that ActiveStorage does work on the files and identify their content type, but in my case it simply cannot identify.

I need ActiveStorage to not to handle extension or content-type, just move the file into the cloud.

I have configured ActiveStorage to work with S3 and attaching files by:

```
instance.attach(io: File.open('VALID_FILE_PATH_HERE'), filename: 'filename.apk')
```

I also tried providing

```
content_type: "application/vnd.android.package-archive"
```

But it did not change anything, and when I append

```
identify: false
```

It throws an exception, saying unexpected key for identify.

Is there a way to make ActiveStorage simply move the file as it is?